# firestore Geopoints why could not call a class as a function error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using import @react-native-firebase/firestore Lib I want to insert into firestore database a location type geopoints the problem is that keeps firing error  saying

> Cannot call a class as a function

here's how I am calling the function and location is my firestore field :

```
location : firestore.GeoPoint(lat, long)
```

I have also tried to import separately firebase from :

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
```

and then :

```
location : firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(lat, long)
```

I still geting the same error , I have also tried with :

```
firebase.firestore.GeoPoint.latitude = lat ; 
...
```

it did not work , could you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that `firestore.GeoPoint` is a class, and you are trying to call it as a function.

To create an instance of `firestore.GeoPoint`, do:

```
location : new firestore.GeoPoint(lat, long)
         //
```